# Leakage current in UART RXD

Tags: uart

I have connected a microprocessor to a bluetooth module using UART. During the sleep of my microprocessor, I measured 7.8uA flowing from uC's rxd to bluetooth module's txd. I measured 70k pull-up to 2.8V on uC's rxd side and open-circuit on bluetooth module's side. Will this configuration causes leakage current in UART line?

Comment: You should include information/part number of your  microprocessor and bluetooth module.

Comment: Any current _actually_ flowing from uC's rxd into anything connected to that ultimately drains power from what powers the uC (which likely is its power supply, though that could also be another leakage current). What are the respective power supply voltage of uC and bluetooth module during sleep?

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty common (you did not mention what type of uC you use) that you manually have to disable/reconfigure peripherals before entering sleep/power down mode to prevent situations like that.
It ranges from disabling hardware interfaces like ADC, brown-out, watchdog to simple things like changing the direction of an IO pin and its pull-up configuration to prevent leakage currents.